# jQuery Datepicker show old date when click on now button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

When I click on 'Now' button its shows me correct date time only first time. but when click 2nd time or more it shows wrong (some old date time value)
[image]

This my working code

```js
$('.from-date-picker').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
  timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
  showOn: "both",
  timeInput: true,
  stepHour: 1,
  stepMinute: 5,
  oneLine: true,
  //changeMonth: true,
  //changeYear: true,
  controlType: 'select',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
  buttonText: "Select date"
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control from-date-picker" name="SaleOrder.Date" id="SaleOrderDate" readonly>
```

Comment: The Now button looks like it's disabled.

Comment: Have you tried a more recent version of jquery-ui?   1.9 was released in 2012.

Answer (score 2):

When I run the following code, the date and time change on the first click to the correct value. When I click on it a second time, the date will sometimes revert to 12:00.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.from-date-picker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
    showOn: "both",
    timeInput: true,
    stepHour: 1,
    stepMinute: 5,
    oneLine: true,
    controlType: 'select',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonText: "Select date"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control from-date-picker" name="SaleOrder.Date" id="SaleOrderDate" readonly>
```

Tested with more modern versions.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.from-date-picker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
    showOn: "both",
    timeInput: true,
    stepHour: 1,
    stepMinute: 5,
    oneLine: true,
    controlType: 'select',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonText: "Select date"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control from-date-picker" name="SaleOrder.Date" id="SaleOrderDate" readonly>
```

It is now working as expected. So this may have been a Bug in the older timepicker code.

Comment: it worked! but problem is. on the same page I am also using jquery.mcautocomplete.js its style blown away.

Comment: @WaqasJavaid there was no way to know that from your example or post. If I had to guess, I suspect there is a conflicting style sheet.